# Is there a way to import index files with postgres?

Tags: postgresql

i'm seeing deadlocks with concurrent index creations with no other db users. i have a large single table with multiple indices.

is there a way that i could use multiple PG instances to create the indices i need in parallel, stop each postgres, and import those index files into a single pg instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deadlocks like this can happen if you create several indexes on the same table concurrently.

Create them one after the other.

You cannot copy a data file from one database to another, be it a table or an index.